# Discord.js Is there any way to get all users to separate variables?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is there any way to get all id's of users in one server to separate variables?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but I doubt there to be any case where you'd actually want to do it. Sounds like a list or an array is what you want. Can you maybe say what you're looking to do?

Comment: I wanted to do something like muteall command

Comment: Yeah, creating a separate variable for each user is definitely not what you'd want to do. You'd just loop through the desired users and do the action you want. I think your question is more about javascript than discord. If you have some specific problem with your javascript code, I suggest you submit a question for that. Remember to use the javascript tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, kind. You could loop through with a for loop then run whatever code you want to on the desired user.

```js
// Where '888888888888888888' is your server id
const server = client.guilds.get("888888888888888888"); 

// Go through each of the members, and console.log() their name
server.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username)); 
//Replace console.log() with what you want to do to them. (e.x give role, ban, kick, dm)
```